# what will effected if vs2010 install on already contain vs2005 in a system?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, conflict, windows-xp-sp3

I have an issue that I am using Visual Studio 2005 on my system with Windows XP SP1 as an operating system. Now I want to install Visual Studio 2010 with SP3 without uninstalling VS2005.

My question is, will my project in VS2005 still work properly? Can I work in both versions without any conflicting issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible. According to the MSDN Documentation([Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) you can install them side by side.

You can't however open a VS2010 project in VS2005. So you need to keep your work strictly separated between those versions if you want to be able to open your project in VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

I have VS2005, 2008 and 2010 all running on the same Vista box with no conflicts. As long as you don't upgrade your 2005 projects (by choosing to open them in VS2010 and accepting the upgrade prompt) you'll be fine.

The big question here is: *will VS2010 actually run on XP SP1?*

Comment: I am using xp sp2 but vs2010 runs on sp3. So that way I asked.